# Entity Framework and SQL Server datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF with SQL Server and when I'm fetching a DateTime field that is DateTime on the MSSQL and on EF, I would get something like this:

```
"UpdateTime":"\/Date(1358716865533+0200)\/"
```

I have no idea what format is this (only that it shows some time with GMT+2 offset).

Any suggestions?

Second, I've tried to use ToString("") on that fields inside the LINQ that fetches the records and got an error that SQL doesn't support formatting this way - so I have no easy way to format that date as I want.
Is there any way to apply formatting?

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: I thought so as well - but this number is longer than the UNIX time. how come?

Comment: OK. Works out - really is UNIX time but with some extra 3 digits, which after being removed resolved to a real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment, this is a Unix format. You'll get a similar string when you serialize a `DateTime` with [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) (JSON).

As for your second question. Yes it can be a nuisance that EF does not allow `ToString` in linq queries. On the other hand, EF is for data access, formatting is for UI. So you better do the formatting after you've fetched data from the database into memory display them somewhere.